# add/remove elements in array-like object

Tags: javascript

I have an array-like object:

[`1:Array[10], 2: Array[2], 3: Array[2], 4: Array[2], 5: Array[3], 6: Array[1]]`

Im trying to remove the first two elements, do some stuff, and then insert them again at the same place.

Here is what i do:

```
array = Array.prototype.splice.call(array, 0,2);
```

When logging `array` in firefox it show this:

```
Array [ <2 empty slots>, Array[1], Array[2], Array[3], Array[1] ]
```

Looks good to me,I removed the first two elements and the array now starts with 2 empty slots.

So now, what I hope to do is to add objects to these 2 empty slots.

For simplicity, lets remove to items from the array and then insert them again at the same place:

```
var twoFirstItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(array, 0,2);
array = Array.prototype.splice.call(array, 0,2);
```

Now,to re-insert `twoFirstItems`  I would think that I could do:

```
array.unshift(twoFirstItems)
```

This does not work as expected, it inserts the array but it does not have a `key` as it had before its modifikation. I assume this has to do with `unshift` not working the same with an `array-like object` as with an `array`.

So how do you remove/insert elements to an `array-like-object` properly?

If i do the following:

```
  console.log(array);
  console.log(typeof array);
```

The result:

```
Array [ <1 empty slot>, Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[3], Array[1] ]
object
```

Comment: what do you mean by array-like, when you work with an array?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be an ordinary array but when i do:
console.log(typeof array)
it logs 'object'.

Comment: why not use the index of the array?

Comment: And if you check if it's an array the correct way. what does it say -> `console.log(Array.isArray(array) )`

Comment: Please see edit where I log datatype

Comment: @adeneo
Weird..when i checked the way you said it logged true...So i guess it is an rray after all?

Comment: `typeof []` always returns `object`, all arrays are objects as well and `typeof` is not designed to distinguish different types of objects.

Comment: You should do `array instanceof Array` to check for `Array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any complications, you can just `re-assign` the modified array at that index.

```js
var a = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

]

a[0] = a[0].map((el) => el * 10)
a[1] = a[1].map((el) => el * 20)

console.log(a)
```